# Duplicates in one column with ONLY 2 values(/A & B) in another column

Tags: duplicates, unique

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFPKb.png)

The last column F in the image is what is expected. Please how do I go about it? Columns A, B, C D, and E would have to be considered to get F. I am using Excel.
Thanks

1. I tried using if and count if.
2. I was expecting the sum of the F column to be 3 instead of the sum of 4 in column E